# How can I get my images to auto Align in a "collage style" inside a div/tab/ul container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im self taught and don't know anything about code from scratch, I just edit templates, and after hours of getting image properties the way I wanted, I have a new problem that I just CANOT solve.

I have looked online but I wasn't able to find an answer.
Here is my problem: (great... cant post images...)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxfsB.jpg

Assuming the images are the same size, I made the perfect padding to my liking, but it all changed when I started uploading all of the photos.
Im hoping there is a way to somehow have the images display in a collage style, so no matter the size, they will all be within the right distance.

**NOTE** 
Even having it to where the bottom images aren't alined is ok.

My style.css

```
ul.gallery                          { list-style:realative; margin: 0px 0;  padding: 0; overflow:hidden;}                                                               
    ul.gallery li                       { display:block; float:left; margin: 5px 10px 5px 0; position: relative;}
    ul.gallery li.alt                   { margin-right: 1px 0;}
    ul.gallery li img                   { padding: 5px; background: #cec4a9; width: 129px; height: 129;px }
```

HTML:

```
</div>
                <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">                    
            <ul class="gallery">                               
                <li class="alt"><a href="img/gal/IEM01.jpg"><img src="img/gal/IEM01.jpg"/></a></li>
```

I can post Js or fancybox css if needed, as long as you specify the right file. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with fancybox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is also known as the "tumbler effect" or "pinterest effect", since these are two websites that used it for a while now. The easiest way to go is using [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/). What masonry does is calculate the rendered size of each of the elements and positions them absolutely so they all tile up nicely. And for now, this is the only way to go if you want to have **only one continuous list of items**.

An alternative to this would be to divide your list of items in how many columns you want to have and render all columns side-by-side, eventually changing the number of columns and redistributing items on the fly using javascript or any other client side script alternative in order to give it responsiveness.

But again, most people use masonry for this and don't even ask themselves how the effect is achieved technically.